# How to list all azure app service with private endpoint enabled or disabled using powershell

Tags: private, azure-powershell, endpoint, azure-appservice

https://stackoverflow.com
How to list all azure app service with private endpoint enabled or disabled using powershell.![What more need to be added to get private endpoint status  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuET2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API from microsoft to achieve sure needs :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language#resource-graph-tables

Doing something like

````sh
Search-AzGraph -Query "Resources 
| where type=~ 'microsoft.xxx/xxx' 
| where name contains 'contoso' 
| project subscriptionId, name, location, resourceGroup, Capacity = toint(sku.capacity), Tier = sku.name 
| order by Capacity desc" ```
````